# jquery fade in fade out issue - initial image not displaying

Tags: jquery, fade, out

Hi I have been using some code that lets me change the background image in a divider by fading in and out. However the issue I have is that when I initially load the page there's no image on display...the first image fades in after five seconds. I would like an image to be displayed first, which then fades in and out.

I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would  be much appreciated. I'm using the following code in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() {           
        var i =0; 
        var images = ['image2.jpg','image3.jpg','image1.jpg'];
        var image = $('#slideit');
        image.css('background-image', 'image1.jpg)');
        setInterval(function(){         
            image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
            image.fadeIn(1000);
            });
            if(i == images.length)
                i = 0;
        }, 5000);            
    });
</script>
```

Then in the body:

```
<div id="slideit" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: There seems a typo... it should be`image.css('background-image', 'image1.jpg');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to set the fisrt image in your HTML:

```
<div id="slideit" style="width:100%;height:100%;background-image: url(image2.jpg)"></div>
```

or set it using javascript:

```
image.css('background-image', 'url(image2.jpg)');
```

It seems like you are missing the `url(...)` in line 6.

Comment: Ohh fantastic thank you - yes I'd missed out the URL, now works perfectly!